# Permission denied when running compass

Tags: html, css, ruby, windows, compass

I installed ruby and compass on my PC and I want to start compass watch command, but i have error message in my git bash command line 
"bash: /c/Program Files/Ruby22-x64/bin/compass: "C:/Program: bad interpreter: Permission denied"
What i must do?

Comment: Solved by reinstalling Ruby on C:/Ruby

Answer (score 0):

Solved by reinstalling Ruby on C:/Ruby and reinstalling compass